# OnScroll Event in ListView using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listView and when the receive a message, the listview should scroll to the end only, if it already in the end.

To make it clear, if the user is seeing old message, the listview shouldn't scroll to the end automatically, but if the is already on the on the listview when receiving a message the listview should automatically scroll to the end.

So I have to get the actual position of the ListView, I didn't see any property or method similar to get this position on the API.

So I was thinking if is possible to override an event like OnScroll, so I can save the current position of the ListView without using custom render.

This can be done using XamarinForms?

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` doesn't fire `Scrolled` events like `ScrollView` does, but it does fire [`ItemAppearing`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemAppearing) and [`ItemDisappearing`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemDisappearing)events that you may be able to use to keep track of which items are currently visible.

Comment: which is terrible, btw

Comment: I agree 100%. Unfortunately I don't see any other way without using custom renderers.

Comment: Any 3rd-party examples where we can see `Scrolled` event implemented?

Comment: @Mark13426 you can try syncfusion listview